# Equivalent of CONCAT_GROUP for multiple columns

Tags: sql

Do you have any idea on how to display values obtained by concat_group in multiple columns instead of having a unique column containing all the values separated by commas.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possibly you are looking for PIVOT.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And do you happen to mean `group_concat()` instead of `concat_group`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in SQL.

One of the fixed rules of SQL is that the columns in your select-list must be set at the time you prepare your query. The select-list does not expand dynamically to match the values it finds as it examines the data.

This comes from the origins of SQL in the relational model. A relation (not a *relationship*, lots of people get this wrong) is a data structure with a fixed set of columns, a header defining the names and data types of the columns, and then a set of rows, where every row has the same set of columns as the header.

The select-list of an SQL SELECT statement effectively defines the header of the relation returned as the result-set of that query. The number and names of the columns are defined by the query, not by the data in the result.

A commenter above asks if you want to do a pivot, but a pivot also requires that you name the columns in the select-list. There is no such thing as a SQL pivot query that grows its select-list according to the data in the result.

Comment: What about dynamic query?

Comment: As I said, you have to have all the column in the select-list defined at the time you **prepare()** the query. Whatever you do in your code to concatenate expressions into the select-list is before the prepare.